# Bootstrap 4 form not sending contents of select box

Tags: html, forms, bootstrap-4

I've written a simple bootstrap 4 form with a GET method, and it only sends the values in the Submit button, not in the  tag above it.

This is eventually to be handled in a POST request, but I've changed it to GET to more easily see what data the form is sending.

Here is the form code:

```
<form action="/picknumbers" method="GET">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="numberselect">Select one or more numbers</label>
        <select multiple class="form-control mb-3" id="numberselect" size="6">
            <option>1</option>
            <option selected>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>
            <option>6</option>
        </select>
    </div>
<button name="submission" value="numberspicked" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Choose numbers</button>
</form>
```

The output in the browser address bar is simply: `/picknumbers?submission=numberspicked`, without including the numbers picked by the user. How do I get the submitted form to include them?

Comment: Doesn't your select element need a name attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give a value on the options also you need to give a name to the select.  To clarify, see the code below:

```
 <select multiple class="form-control mb-3" name="select-name" id="numberselect" size="6">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2" selected>2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your select options appear to be missing value attribute tags. It should look like the below:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="numberselect">Select one or more numbers</label>
        <select multiple class="form-control mb-3" id="numberselect" size="6">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2" selected>2</option>
           ... 
        </select>
    </div>
<button name="submission" value="numberspicked" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Choose numbers</button>
</form>
```